# SwiftUI navigationBarItems disappear in TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that has navigation bar items and I embed that view in a `TabView`. But when doing that, the bar items no longer appear. If I call the view outside of a `TabView` everything works as expected.

Below a small sample project to illustrate my issue, note that the `TabView` is not called on the initial `ContentView` but later down:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: WarehouseOrderTabView()){
                Text("Click me")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct WarehouseOrderTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            TabView1().navigationBarTitle("Dashboard")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gauge")
                    Text("Dashboard")
            }

            TabView2().navigationBarTitle("Orders")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    Text("Orders")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TabView 1")
            //I would expect to see those bar items when displaying tab 1
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: (
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                            .font(.title)
                    })
                        .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
                    Button(action: {

                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                            .font(.title)
                    })
                }
            ))
    }
}

struct TabView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TabView 2")
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `TabView` cannot be in `NavigationView`, vice-versa can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `NavigationView` can be embedded in a `TabView` and not vice-versa.

`TabView` contains different `tabItem()` (at most 5) that can contain your views.

This is how you can use it.

TabView1.swift

```
struct TabView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("TabView 1")
                .navigationBarTitle("Dashboard")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            // more code here
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            // more code here
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

TabView2.swift

```
struct TabView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: YourNewView()) {
                Text("TabView 1")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Orders")
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.Swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            TabView1()
               .tabItem {
                   Image(systemName: "gauge")
                   Text("Dashboard")
               }
            TabView2()
               .tabItem {
                   Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                   Text("Orders")
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So if I want to use NavigationViews and TabViews, I have to use the TabView in my whole application? My goal here is to only have specific views that use a tab view while the rest of the application works without.

Comment: In most cases, TabView acts as a root view that embeds other views such as NavigationView. I haven't seen any application that has a view that embeds a TabView inside itself.

Comment: Thanks! Does not solve my problem but explains why its not working! Accepted your answer because it shows how to fix it!